# Obtener repeticiones array

Tags: javascript

```
var a = {

edades = [12,15,16,2,12,45,60,15]

};

for(var i=0;i<a;i++) {

  console.log("Soy:" +i);
}
```

***Como cuento si hay numeros repetidos en el `array` edades, y si se repiten solo ejecutar las instrucciones una vez(pero solo por ese elemento)*** ?

Osea si hubiera:

```
var b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1];
```

El que se repite es el 1 , entonces mostraria:

`,2,3,4,5,6,7,1` y el primer 1 no ya que se repite

Comment: Edita la pregunta y el título ya que hay ahora mismo dos cosas un tanto diferentes. El primer código y lo que está en negrita no cuadra con la segunda parte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más sencilla es convertir el Array en un tipo de dato "Set". Un conjunto (Set) no contiene elementos repetidos.

Un ejemplo:

```
var a = [1, 1, 2, 3]
var b = new Set(a)
b.forEach(x => console.log(x))
```

Salida:

```
1
2 
3
```

**Actualizo**

En ese caso, puedes hacerlo así:

```
> var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,1]
> var b = new Set()
> a.reverse().forEach(x => b.add(x))
> c = Array.from(b).reverse()
```

Valor de `c`:

```
Array [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1 ]
```

Comment: necesito diferente orden

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

En este código utilizo un array asociativo, cuya clave de los elementos es el número del array edades.

En la primera pasada del array edades creo el array asociativo para controlar que en la segunda pasada sólo saquemos una vez cada elemento.

```js
var a = {

  edades : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,1]

};

// Array para controlar si hemos sacado ya o no un elemento
var aListar = {};

// Array asociativo en el que me guardo si tengo que sacar el elemento en el listado (true) o si ya lo he sacado antes (false). La clave del array es el elemento origen
for (var i = 0; i < a.edades.length; i++) {
  aListar[a.edades[i]] = true;
}

var cad = ''; // Cadena para sacar los elementos finales en el mismo orden

// Empiezo a leer el array origen por detrás
for (var i = a.edades.length; i>0; i--) {
  if ( aListar[a.edades[i]] ) {
     // Su elemento del array asociativo está a true, por lo que no he listado este elemento aún
     aListar[a.edades[i]] = false;  // Marco para no sacarlo más veces
     cad = ',' + a.edades[i] + cad;
  }
}
document.write( cad );
```

Comment: NetVicious mira mi ultima edicion por favor

Comment: Eliminar todos los duplicados, excepto el ultimo

Comment: Porque el 1 en el array asociativo?

Comment: Netvicious, no pongas una respuesta que sea solo codigo. intenta explicar tu codigo pues la explicacion es lo que nutre la respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: Y podrias explicarme la logica de la ultima parte del codigo osea donde eliminas las repeticiones? para entenderlo y asi usarlo en un futuro

Comment: Podría ser un true, y luego cuando comparas miras si está a true o no. Si quiere lo cambio. Tomé código de otro proyecto donde contaba los duplicados. Dicho array asociativo sirve para saber si ya hemos sacado ese elemento o no. Digamos que en la primera pasada del array origen me apunto que elementos están en el array. Todos tendrán un 1, incluso los duplicados. Al procesar el array al reves en la segunda parte al sacar uno que esté duplicado pondré su array asociativo a 0 y así los siguientes repetidos no saldrán.

Comment: @lois6b si te fijas mi código está lleno de comentarios explicándolo todo

Comment: @Eduardo Sebastian. He cambiado el nombre del array asociativo y he metido más comentarios en el código.

Comment: Si, pero son comentarios de codigo, no una explicación. Mira [answer].

Comment: @lois6b, hecho.

Comment: No entiendo la parte de if ( aListar[a.edades[i]] ) , porque si hago un consolelog a aListar salen todos sus valores en true

Comment: Te lo explico y me dices que nombre le pondrías tu a ese array asociativo. Veamos, tu quieres sacar sólo una vez cada elemento, para así quitar los duplicados. Digamos que ese array asociativo tiene un flag para cada valor (repetido o no) del array origen. Una vez se lista (de ahí el aListar) un elemento se marca como ya listado (se quita el flag) para así no listar las siguientes repeticiones de dicho elemento.